# igraph Create an edge between one pre-determined and another random node whilst taking into account attributes

Tags: r, igraph

I currently have a code like the following which randomly removes a single edge from a random graph:

```
library(igraph)

g <- erdos.renyi.game(20, 50 , type = "gnm" , directed = F , loops = F) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("a", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("aa", value = 0) %>%
  set_edge_attr("b", value = 0) %>%
  set_vertex_attr("z", value = 0) 

V(g)$aa <- sample(c(0, .25, .5, .75, 1), vcount(g), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.15, 0.3, 0.15, 0.1))


V(g)$a[V(g)$aa <= V(g)$z & V(g)$a == 0] <- 1

V(g)$z <- sapply(V(g), function(x) { 
    NeighborList = neighbors(g, x) ; 
    ifelse(length(NeighborList) > 0, 
    length(NeighborList[NeighborList$a == 1])/length(NeighborList),0) } )


sum <- sum(head_of(g,E(g))$a==0 & tail_of(g,E(g))$a==0)

E(g)$b[head_of(g,E(g))$a==0 & tail_of(g,E(g))$a==0] <- sample(rep(0:1, c(sum-1, 1)), sum)

g <- delete_edges(g, E(g)[E(g)$b == 1])

plot(g)
```

After removing the edge between these two nodes, I want to generate a new, single edge that connects the node that a lower attribute value for "aa" to a random node that has an even lower attribute value for "aa" without creating duplicate edges. How would I go about doing this?

So for example, if the edge that was deleted randomly connected nodes 1 ("aa" == .5) and 2 ("aa" == 1). I want the code to generate a single, new edge that connects node 1 and any other node that has a "aa" value of .25 or 0 without it being a duplicate edge.

Comment: What should happen if there is no node with a lower aa value?

Comment: I changed the code so that there will always be a node that has a lower aa value. However, if my code does not work as intended and there is no node with a lower aa value, I would like for it to connect to a node that has the same aa value.